# Select user entries and following entries at the same time with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, photo

I have a MySQL database with a photos table (containing the photos) and a follows table (containing information about users following users).

I have the following code to load photos from the users that the current user is following:

```
SELECT photos.* FROM photos,follows 
WHERE follows.following = photos.uid AND 
      follows.follower=$current_uid 
ORDER BY photos.id DESC
```

I want to load a list of both my user's uploaded photos as well as the ones that user is following.  I tried the following, but I keep getting a whole bunch of duplicate entries:

```
SELECT photos.* 
FROM photos,follows 
WHERE (follows.following = photos.uid AND 
       follows.follower=$current_uid) OR 
       photos.uid=$current_uid
ORDER BY photos.id DESC
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  photos.*
FROM
  photos
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  follows
ON
  photos.uid = follows.following AND follows.follower = $current_uid
WHERE
  photos.uid = $current_uid
OR
  follows.following IS NOT NULL
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT
  photos.*
FROM
  photos
WHERE
  photos.uid = $current_uid
OR
  photos.uid IN (SELECT following FROM follows WHERE follower = $current_uid)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!  I always get confused with joins so this clears some of it up for me.

Comment: By saying you want to select from both tables, but not specifying any condition linking them in the `OR` part of your query, you basically told the database to give you the photos of `$current_uid` paired up with every row (of all users) in the follows table. Thus all the duplicates. When you can, please click the big checkmark icon to the left of this answer to show your question is solved.